# Reusable SwingWorker sub-class for whole program

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I need to make a generic `SwingWorker` process to use it in all my program.
My class is like this:

```
public class LoadingSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    private WaitingDiag diag;

    private Statistics st = new Statistics();

    public LoadingSwingWorker(GraphEditor editor, Statistics st) {  //st variable
        this.st = st;
        Window mainWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(editor
                .getGraphComponent().getParent());
        diag = new WaitingDiag(mainWindow, "Loading data...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        st.loadInitialData();   //st method
        return 42;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        diag.dispose();
    }

    public void openDiag() {
        diag.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

For all my program, I may need to create `SwingWorker` classes **as much as** I need for long_time tasks (`st` variable in that case), is not possible to implement generic one

Comment: I tired to find solution in that way, but how can create interface from that extends a class?

Comment: Use the `interface` so you can pass it to the `SwingWorker`...

Comment: SwingWorker couldn't completed, but depends on ...., important would be a question, for why reason, because SwingWorker isn't reausable, nor shareable